# How to merge two unordered_maps without changing the order of the elements?

Tags: c++, dictionary, merge, stl, unordered-map

I need to merge two `unordered_map`s without changing the order. 
For example,

```
unordered_map<int,int> map1 ,map2, map3;
```

map1 contains : <4,4> <2,2>

map2 contains : <3,3> <1,1>

map1 and map2 to be merged with map3.

so my map3 should contain <4,4><2,2><3,3><1,1>

```
map<int,int>::iterator it   = map3.begin();
std::merge(map1.begin(),map1.end(),map2.begin(),map2.end(),inserter(map3,it));
```

Still map3 order is changing.
I have tried with std::merge and insert, but nothing worked as per the above req. Can someone help me on this. or am i doing some mistake on merge and insert?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`std::unordered_map` doesn't guarantee any kind of order, while `std::map` is always in sorted order by key (though you can specify your own comparison function). It looks like you want items in their order of insertion. In this case you can just push your data to a `std::vector`, although you will have to give up the sublinear operations that the mapped types provide.

Comment: So you mean to say, unordered map will do some kind of sort on key while inserting?

Comment: No. In practice `std::unordered_map` is a [hash table](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hash_table). I'm not sure how explicitly the standard specifies it, but it certainly walks like a hash table and quacks like a hash table. It'll *probably* iterate in sorted order of hashes (and, within the same hash bucket, in the order of insertion), but that's certainly not guaranteed. So when you iterate from `begin` to `end`, you can rely on hitting all the elements, but that's pretty much it.

Answer (score 0):

There order of map elements dependent of its keys and balanced tree algorithm but not of source map elements order. If you want to save order use `std::vector<std::pair<inr,int>>` instead.

Answer (score 0):

std::merge works assuming two already sorted ranges (in your case two unsorted maps) achieving linear time performance. Due to its implementation, using unsorted maps will not give the required result.